# Correct php date/time pattern

Tags: php, datetime

i have this date/time format:

```
Fri, 17 Oct 2014 22:12:51 +3:30
```

I know that correct pattern is :

```
'D, d M Y H:i:s P'
```

but when use this encounter with this error :

```
Impossible to guess date format :
 Fri, 17 Oct 2014 22:12:51 +3:30
```

i think this error happen because the +3:30 (GMT) isn't true and true is +03:30 . i don't know how to solve it?!
(I' m using a debril_rss_atom in symfony for reading rss , rss of the sites have a publish date attribute , and debril have a part for reading a publish date according to a pattern :)

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $default = array(
            \DateTime::RFC3339,
            \DateTime::RSS,
            \DateTime::W3C,
            'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP',
            'Y-m-d',
            'd M Y H:i:s +O',
            'D, d M Y H:i:s',
            'D, d M Y H:i:s +P',
            'D, d M Y H:i:s +O',

        );

        if (!isset($config['date_formats']))
        {
            $container->setParameter(
                    'debril_rss_atom.date_formats', $default
            );
        } else
        {
            $container->setParameter(
                    'debril_rss_atom.date_formats', array_merge($default, $config['date_formats'])
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add code sample to help others reproduce your error

Comment: Did you try without the "+" in your format identifier because "P" option already includes it ?

Comment: i test this with + and without + .

Comment: In order to ensure that you problem comes from this missing 0, did you try `'D, d M Y H:i:s +3:30'` to see if it returns something ?

Comment: No answer with this way. i' m tested same your answer ,

Answer (score 1):

All your formats are standard, so no need for guessing the format, `DateTime` is more than capable of doing that on its own:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('Fri, 17 Oct 2014 22:12:51 +3:30');
print_r($dt);
```

<sub>In your method `load()` you have used format `+O` and `+P` which is not ok. `O` and `P` also take into account the plus/minus before the timezone offset, so no need for specifying the sign before the format.</sub>

Comment: i know this , but if i don't add + , give me a error.!!? (I wonderful for this?!) , i solve my problem by removing +3:30 from pubDate.Thankyou

Comment: @RoohbakhshMasoud: can you show me the error you receive?

Comment: Impossible to guess date format :
Sun, 19 Oct 2014 23:24:15 +3:30
500 Internal Server Error - ParserException

Comment: That is your error.. What doesn't work, if you try it my way?

Comment: I don't know (this is my question ?!). thanks for your helping .